# How to model Storage Capacity in BPMN?

Tags: process, simulation, modeling, bpmn, capacity

I am right now trying to model a warehouse with import and export processes. I have the problem that I do not know how I should model the capacity of different storage places in the warehouse. There are processes where vehicles with different loadings come and all of them need to be stored in the warehouse with a limited capacity. Else the arriving goods have to be declined.

I am modeling this process in a BPM Suite and was thinking about using Python to access this problem. I thought that I could simply use variables and if clauses to check the capacity of each storage. But if I would simulate this process with this approach then the variables are re-instantiated each time with the start value and do not hold the actual value., beucause with the script is included in the model as a script task.

Does anyone has other ideas to model capacity in BPMN?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you share what you have done so far, e.g. by posting a BPMN diagram, please?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to not use BPMN as it is clearly adds more complexity than benefit in your case? Look at the [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) which allows to specify orchestration logic using normal code and would support your requirements directly without any ugly workarounds.